# Best way to clue reader into a character's backstory?

Tags: backstory

I'm currently making a draft for my next writing project, and I'm not sure if one of my ideas is something I should do.

Is it a good idea to only give snippets of backstory, through the actions of the characters in the first chapter, and reveal more as the story develops? For example, if a character is in a conversation, and they vaguely mention something that happened in their past (as a way to give the reader a better understanding of the character), would that be an effective way to go about this?

A related question, if this *is* a good idea, what would be the best way to go about it? Should I write the characters to give hints about their past through their actions, or should I make it more obvious for the reader?

**Edit 1:** Wow, everyone, thanks for all the  advice! I've gotten a lot of great feedback from some (hopefully) wonderful people, and I've marked an answer as accepted. *BUT* if you guys want to keep giving feedback, it would still be super helpful! Again, thanks everyone!

Comment: Gradually revealing the backstory is a good idea if that's an important part of the story. (Like solving a murder mystery, but in this case the mystery of who the character is.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a good idea. Do not overwhelm the reader with info in the beginning.  Still, give them *some* info about the characters to introduce them.

As to how you should sneak in extra info, well...

### Gossip

How do we learn things about each other? That's right, when somebody feels the need to share some juicy gossip.

Like when you start a new job and somebody tells you that it would be best if you didn't mention the Vietnam War around old Mr. Jones, because he was *there*.

### Stray thoughts

If you are inside the head of a character, you can have licence to have all sorts of memories pop up.  This reminds you of that.  Don't overdo this, unless you want that character appear as scatter-minded.

### Conversations

Sure, as long as you stay away from "As you know,..."  There are still scenes where one character genuinely needs to tell something to another.

Also, friends just chatting will often reminiscence about shared experiences.

Don't dump too much info in one place or lose readers.   Even if a conversation is not brief in-universe, you don't need to show the whole thing.

### Action!

If you need to inform the readers that a character is capable of something, just let them do it!  So, she can read Russian?  Just show her reading Dostoevsky in the original when another characters arrives at the scene.

### Straight narration

Be very careful with that.  The rule is "Show, don't tell".  Only rarely is narration the best solution.

### Foreshadowing and hints

When a writer listens to their readers, one of the best things they can hear is "It totally surprised me, but it made perfect sense in retrospect."

This is foreshadowing done *right*. Foreshadowing can fail in two ways,  first way is when the reader sees the surprise coming. "Yeah yeah, she was nauseous in the morning, so she was pregnant. Big whooping surprise."

The other way it can fail is if the reader fail to pick up the hint and the end surprise still feels like an Deus ex Machina.

The balance is difficult.  The best advice I have is to ask yourself "Will the story as whole still work if this foreshadowing fails one way or the other?"  If no, you should rethink.

### All of the above!

Mix it up!  Don't be a one-trick pony.

Answer (score 5):

IRL, how do you reveal **your** backstory to others?

In conversation, often with somebody new. A job interview, a date, a new friend you meet doing something related to your hobby. You go sign up for a karate dojo in a new town. The general order of karate belts is white (novice), yellow, green, blue, brown and black (expert), you list yours as brown, training for black. Teachers in Karate are called "sensei", the sensei asks you where you got your training. You answer some of it six years as a Navy Seal, then you continued in Chicago after you left the military. But you just moved to Seattle for a new job, and you are looking for a new dojo.

Voila, back story.

As an author, invent scenes for your characters in which revealing their backstory seems like the natural thing to do for the situation. Don't just dump it by "telling", invent a scene so there is a **reason** for the character to tell somebody.

Comment: Or invent a scene that justifies using a flashback.

Answer (score 4):

Effectiveness is a matter of execution. You have a few tools at your disposal, which are action, narrative, and dialog (to simplify.)

In dialog, a character's history can naturally be conveyed. Same with narrative. This is a bit of a blunt tool. But effective, and balance is key.

Actions are interesting because those can draw on psychology and lived experience (Smeagal's psychosis in LOTR showed us, through his actions, the extent of his brokenness.)

Use all the tools. Find balance. Rewrite to find a better balance. Newly-met characters might de-brief more than old friends. Please, do not infodump. Please, do not use 'as you know Bob' dialog.

In general, a cost to the character buys a credit of infodump. In other words, If a character's brother dies, and they're crying, and they say, "He's the one who taught me to fly-fish when I was ten" ... we are fine with that bit of back story. Because the character's brother just freakin died.

Answer (score 1):

If that was a good idea, don’t you think you’d already have seen it used by the writers you admire most… by four or three of them, for instance?

Please look again at how relevant it might be that you’re making a draft, and not sure if one of your ideas is something you should do. Does that help?

Whether it might be a good idea to only give snippets of back-story, would depend entirely on the context: what story you were telling, and in what style.

Whether it might be a good idea to reveal all or part any back-story through the actions of the characters in the first chapter, and more as the story develops, would still depend on the context, though more clearly on style than content.

If a character is in a conversation and vaguely mentions something that happened in the past, that might indeed give the reader a better understanding of the character, and it might be a good way to introduce a back story and it might be both… and what makes you think they’re the same?

Why not try it? Why not write a test chapter that way, and see what happens?